# How to make ReSharper stop removing blanklines in my invocations?

Tags: resharper

In my repository code, I sometimes use blank lines to separate parameters into groups of 5 so that it's easier to eyeball that the ?s match the parameters. Like so:

```
var sql = $@"
UPDATE MYTABLE SET
MYPROP1 = ?
, MYPROP2 = ?
, MYPROP3 = ?
, MYPROP4 = ?
, MYPROP5 = ?

, MYPROP6 = ?
, MYPROP7 = ?
...
, MYPROP29 = ?
, MYPROP30 = ?

, MYPROP31 = ?
WHERE ID = ?";
var parameters = DBParametre.GetParms(
    1,
    2,
    3,
    4,
    5,

    6,
    7,
...
    29,
    30,

    31,

    id
);
```

The problem is, when I run ReSharper Cleanup Code in the repository file, it removes the blank lines in the middle of the GetParms() invocation. How do I make that stop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [ReSharper help](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/resharper/Enforcing_Code_Formatting_Rules.html#using-comments-to-configure-formatter), you can use the following comments:

`// @formatter:off` — disable formatter after this line

`// @formatter:on` — enable formatter after this line